# Enforce HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/2

Tags: php, apache, curl, cocoapods

I host a file on a server that is fetched by CocoaPods as part of a pod. CocoaPods uses curl internally to fetch this. Curl 7.54.0 in the latest macOS 10.14.2 (18C54) has [a bug](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1618) which causes issues with files fetched over HTTP/2. This means that developers using my pod keep getting install failures due to the curl bug.

As curl is used inside Cocoapods I can't provide command line switches to curl (at least I don't think Cocoapods provides a way to do so).

Is there any way using Apache configuration, htaccess or PHP I can enforce HTTP/1.1?

Comment: i have the same issue. How did you finaly solved it ?

Comment: Sorry I can't remember, but I think I just worked around the issue

Answer (score 0):

`cURL` has a command-line switch `-http1.1`. in PHP that might be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
```

... that's at least what the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION.html) says.

---

`mod_rewrite` can also be used to forbid `HTTP/2.0` (but no clue how to switch it):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PROTOCOL} ^HTTP/2\.0$ [NC]
RewriteRule . [F,L]
```

---

I think that virtual host configuration is the most solid (this won't work in a `.htaccess` file):

```
PolicyVersion enforce HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: I'm not using curl inside PHP, it is being used by CocoaPods on the local computer. I was asking if I can enforce HTTP/1.1 from PHP. I'm not sure if it is the server or client that determines the protocol to use.

Comment: @Nick added further options. both, the server and the client can stick to a protocol version, where ordinary the best available (supported by both) is being negotiated, unless enforcing a lower version.

Comment: I spotted PolicyVersion, but I don't think I can use it as I don't have access to the vhost config :/

Comment: @Nick you could either migrate to a root server - or ask people to add `-http1.1` into `~/.curlrc`, which should then pass the option to the CocoaPods downloader, which most likely uses `curl` via CLI (the dowside is just, that this would downgrade any request to `HTTP/1.1`).

Answer (score 0):

You can decide which version to use by setting the option `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION`

```
// default, lets CURL decide which version to use    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NON);

// forces HTTP/1.0
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);

// forces HTTP/1.1    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
```

Comment: `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1` is a constant which has a long value; it's not a string.

Comment: I'm not using curl inside PHP, it is being used by CocoaPods on the local computer. I was asking if I can enforce HTTP/1.1 from PHP. I'm not sure if it is the server or client that determines the protocol to use.